# Form, input, onMouseOver - onMouseOut and browsers

Tags: forms, jsp, browser, onmouseover, onmouseout

I've a form (POST) with this INPUT (a line), in a JSP file:

```
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Executar" name="1" id="Execute"
style="visibility:hidden" onMouseOver="window.status='URL: http://jlex1x2-uocpfc.rhcloud.com'" 
onMouseOut="window.status=''">
```

It works with:

- IE 6 and Mozilla Firefox 36.0.4: See my onMouseOver.

It doesn't work with:

- Mozilla Firefox 9.01 and Chrome 41.0: Nothing it appears.
- IE 9: It appears '*.rhcloud.com/directory/filename.jsp#'

EDIT 2 APR:

- My form (simplifyed) is this (without my textarea):

:

```
<FORM action="#" METHOD="POST"> 
... // Initial code
</FORM>
```

I would like to improve my INPUT (for all browsers) with only '*.rhcloud.com'.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me..Just remove the `style="visibility"`.
Here is my code and output screenshot :

```html
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Executar" name="1" id="Execute"
onmouseover="window.status='http://jlex1x2-uocpfc.rhcloud.com'" 
onmouseout="window.status=''">
```

[image: Output Screenshot]

Comment: It doesn't work (for me) in IE 9 and others. I've edited my post. Also I added 'URL: ' in onMouseOver.

Comment: With your snipped I obtain the same results. So, it works with IE 6 and Mozilla Firefox 37.0 (OK with the pluggin Status-4-Evar), but not with IE 9, Chrome 41.0 and Mozilla Firefox 9.01 (also with the pluggin mentioned).

Comment: My style is necessary (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431392/to-disable-enable-a-button-submit-in-a-form).